# Change the height of section header Collectionview in viewdidload

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Is it possible to set the height of a collection view section header in the view did load? I am able to set it using a delegate method and in the storyboard but I want to set it in the view did load and then again as the user is scrolling. Basically, it has to be done outside of the delegate method.

Comment: What's wrong with setting it in the delegate method?

Comment: I need to update it as the user is scrolling so basically in the "scrollViewDidScroll"

Comment: Is it possible to set a variable in the scrollViewDidScroll() which is read in the delegate then do a rebuildData()? Might cause some flickering though. You'd need to try it out